# sublime text doesn't auto-complete all php code.

Tags: php, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Sublime Text both 2 and 3 doesn't complete certain variables and functions. I am having a problem with those like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SESSION` and maybe more.

How to solve that and is there a way i can modify auto-completion?

Comment: software specific questions are usually best asked on their own forums

Answer (score 0):

To get `PHP` snippets to work, I had to change the scope within each snippet.

Example, the `$_GET` snippet.
From:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[\$_GET['${1:variable}']]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>$_</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
    <description>GET['…']</description>
</snippet>
```

To

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[\$_GET['${1:variable}']]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>$_</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html - source.php</scope>
    <description>GET['…']</description>
</snippet>
```

Further, you might want to rename the `tabTrigger` to something like `GET`.  This will enable the autocomplete popup.  It seems that special characters don't work well for a `tabTrigger`.  If you keep the same trigger, i.e. `$_`, then you will have to hit <kbd>tab</kbd> before the autocomplete menu appears.